# Emojis are not rendering in the terminal when using the logger.info() , logger.warn, etc

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, emoji, pinojs

When using the console.log() the emojis are rendered in the terminal but when using logger.info() , logger.warn() , etc emojis didn't appropriately render. I used Pino-pretty.

[src/app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pPFu.jpg)
[utils/logger.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmKbB.jpg)

```
import express from "express";

import cors from "cors";
import logger from "./utils/logger";
import "dotenv/config";

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || "8090";

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json({ 
    limit: "20mb" 
}));

app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
res.send("<h2> Library Management System API</h2>");
next();
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on PORT ${PORT}`);
    logger.info(`Listening on PORT ${PORT} `);

    logger.info("This is testing");
    logger.error("This is error");
    logger.warn("This is warning");
});
```

--Output in the terminal--

`[nodemon] restarting due to changes...`

`[nodemon] starting` babel-node src/app.js

`Listening on PORT 8090`

`[24-02-2023 14:37:41] INFO: **≡ƒÜÇ**Listening on PORT 8090`

`[24-02-2023 14:37:41] INFO: This is testing`

`[24-02-2023 14:37:41] ERROR: This is error`

`[24-02-2023 14:37:41] WARN: This is warning`

I expected the relevant emoji but it showed like ≡ƒÜÇ

Answer (score 1):

You have to add "chcp 65001" to your script tag in package.json.

`"scripts": { "start": "chcp 65001 && nodemon --exec file-path" }`